# How can I execute multiple SQL commands at one time with Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework

I have the following code:

```
var sql = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("data_tables.sql");
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql);
```

My data_tables.sql script contains SQL statements such as this:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Application ON
INSERT INTO Application(ApplicationId, Name) VALUES (1, 'xxxx');
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Application OFF
DBCC CHECKIDENT( 'Application', RESEED )
```

Rather than read from a file is there a way I can put these into a class and have the commands execute. What I am looking for is a way to execute all the commands in one go.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Entity Framework exists to make it easier for you to get data from your database to your UI and back, as well as query data using LINQ or extension methods. If your list of SQL statements has something to do with this, then it might be advantageous to do some sort of conversion. If however you're just executing a "dry" list of preprepared SQL statements, then I see no problem with your current setup.

This has a lot to do with what you're trying to do and it's very hard to suggest a strategy without more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `EntityFramework.Extended` to achieve this using the `.Future` queries.

```
// build up queries
var q1 = db.Users
    .Where(t => t.EmailAddress == "one@test.com")
    .Future();

var q2 = db.Tasks
    .Where(t => t.Summary == "Test")
    .Future();

// this triggers the loading of all the future queries
var users = q1.ToList();
```